# Angular Directive get clipboard data from keydown event

Tags: angular, typescript

I created Directive that controls only numeric input,now I want to allow only pasted numeric data. I plan to do the following: check the data in clipbroad if the number is ok, otherwise skip it. 
But I have not found the way to get data from clipbroad, so I have to do it

```
export class NumberOnlyDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp("^[0-9]{0,8}([,.][0-9]{0,3})?$");
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key == "v") {
      return;
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key == "c") {
      return;
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key == "x") {
      return;
    }

    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }

    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not rely on HTMl to do that ?

```
<input type="number">
```

Then, when you submit you form,

```
if (isNaN(this.myControl.value)) {
  console.log('Not a number');
}
```

Comment: (You can also use `isNaN` in your directive by the way)